# Java Swing class cannot be cast into DefaultListModel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, awt

I'm working on a project with Swing and I have the following event handler:

```
private void txtInputKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    

    if (evt.getKeyCode() == ENTER) {
        DefaultListModel listModel = (DefaultListModel) lFrequencyTable.getModel();

        listModel.removeAllElements();

        ArrayList<FrequencyChar> table = 
                engine.computeFrequencyTable(txtInput.getText());

        for (FrequencyChar f: table) {
            listModel.addElement(f.character);
        }
    }
}
```

A lot of the code is auto generated from Netbeans which is why I haven't posted all the UI code. I'm getting an exception when I try to initialize listModel: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: brutus.BrutusUI$2 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel`. `BrutusUI` is the swing UI class generated by NetBeans (it's just the main entry point of the app with all the components). However, NetBeans is showing me that the return value of `lFrequencyTable.getModel();` is a `ListModel` so why would it be trying to cast the UI class as the DefaultListModel?

Answer (score 2):

It is not trying to cast `BrutusUI` to a `DefaultListModel`, but `brutus.BrutusUI$2` where the `$2` means an anonymous class (that implements  `ListModel`) that was declared inside the class `BrutusUI`.

Comment: You don't cast it to `DefaultListModel` but keep it as a `ListModel` and use the `ListModel` methods on it (unless specified otherwise in the `BrutusUI` documentations).

Comment: But ListModel doesn't implement the removeAllElements method.